# Open form based on input from select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to open a form based on input from Form Control Select in Bootstrap 3?

I have 3 forms on a page and would like to display the form based on value (id) from the first select tag.

Have seen this done before, but can't find the page, no luck on Google either (maybe bad search terms).
Thinking this can be done by hiding the forms until it's called.

There's also the option of using Modal, but I prefer having it all on one page for this particular matter.

UPDATE
Still can't display forms, even though @Mat's suggestion works on jsFiddle. Uploading file in hope that someone can spot the error.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Testpage</title>

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script>
//$('#myModal').modal('show');

$('#formSel').change( function() {
var id = $(this).val();
if( id != '-' )
{
    $('form').hide();
    $('#form'+id).show();
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<select id="formSel">
 <option value="-">Select a form</option>
 <option value="1">Form 1</option>
 <option value="2">Form 2</option>
 <option value="3">Form 3</option>
</select>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <form id="form1"><input type="text" value="form 1" /></form>
    <form id="form2"><input type="text" value="form 2" /></form>
    <form id="form3"><input type="text" value="form 3" /></form>
 </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: @ChrVik: put the jQuery block inside `$(document).ready( function() { /* HERE */ });` and it will work

Comment: IT WORKS! A million thanks @Mat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: take a look at this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/blocknotes/Luh1w87d/

Modify your select:

```
<select id="formSel">
  <option value="-">Select a form</option>
  <option value="1">Form 1</option>
  <option value="2">Form 2</option>
  <option value="3">Form 3</option>
</select>
```

And inside your modal you put 3 forms like:

```
<form id="form1">...</form>
<form id="form2">...</form>
<form id="form3">...</form>
```

Use jQuery:

```
$('#formSel').change( function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    if( id != '-' )
    {
        $('form').hide();
        $('#form'+id).show();
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you both! Couldn't fire up the Forms. It should be enough to reference the Jquery in the <head> like this, right? 

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

Comment: If you have a local copy of jquery on that path: yes (BTW jQuery is required by Bootstrap usually, unless you used a custom package) - also check the Javascript console to see if there are some errors logged

Comment: I don't get it, still can't fire up the forms, but both of yours run well in jsFiddle so the error is probably local. No errors in Chrome inspect console either. But at least I now know how it's done.

@Mat you came up first so I'm gonna mark yours as the right answer, but I thank both of you for contributing! (@Gvidas +1 for the fiddle!)

Comment: If it's not working for you then it's not finished yet. I read your question again, I update my answer

Comment: Still not working. Thought it might be something wrong with my local files so I tried CDN for Bootstrap/JQuery, no luck. Uploaded the file so hopefully someone can spot the error. Thanks for your update and effort @Mat!

Answer (score 1):

Here's small [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aqqLwz8u/) with posible solution for your problem.

**HTML**

```
<select class="form-control input-small" id="form-controller">
  <option value="" selected disabled>Choose form</option>
  <option value="Form1">Form1</option>
  <option value="Form2">Form2</option>
  <option value="Form3">Form3</option>
</select>
<form id="Form1"><input type="text" value="Form1"/></form>
<form id="Form2"><input type="text" value="Form2"/></form>
<form id="Form3"><input type="text" value="Form3"/></form>
```

**CSS**

```
form{
    display:none;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#form-controller').change(function(){
    $('form').hide();
    $('form#'+$(this).val()).show();
});
```

You can also select form by option text not value by changing `$(this).val()` to `$("#form-controller option:selected").text()`