# Open div only after selecting option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress with a Ninjaform calculated form. I have a dropdown list, and I would like to display the calculation DIV only after the dropdown is selected, but open automatically.

This is my select input (which I cannot change):

```
<select id="nf-field-5" name="nf-field-5" class="ninja-forms-field nf-element">
<option value="-" selected="selected">Seleccionar kilates</option>
<option value="14k">14k (joyas)</option>
<option value="18k">18k (joyas)</option>
<option value="22k">22k (monedas)</option>
<option value="24k">24k (lingotes)</option>
<option value="no-estoy-seguro-a">No estoy seguro/a</option>
</select>
```

This is my div:

```html
<span>
<div class="calculator-item-list">
  <div class="item-block calculator-item">
    <p><br>
      <span class="weight">Total de oro:</span>
     <span class="headline2">{calc:Total} €</span> 
      <span class="weight">{calc:Susgramos} gramos</span>
     <span class="large">Le pagamos a {calc:Porgramo} € el gramo</span> 
      <span class="weight">Gastos de valoración: -20€</span>
      <br>
      <span class="weight">Precio final:</span>
      <span class="headline">{calc:Totals} €</span>
    </p>
</div></div>
</span>
```

The div I can change and css. Also I can add a script to my header or footer.

Please help me, as I have tried various options but none seem to work.

So ideally, after the user selects an option from the dropdown, the result div shows up, before this it must be hidden.
I know an easy option would be with a hidden checkbox and label for clicking but I need an automatic solution, which works without cliking on any button to submit.

Here is link to my page: https://comprooroenmalaga.com/vender-oro-online/

Many thanks,
Bee

Comment: What have you tried so far? It would be quite simple to just write the code for you but that's not really what StackOverflow is about 

Comment: I tried to use this, but it didn't work for me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33894337/open-form-based-on-input-from-select
Also, I would've used onchange= but as I cannot modify the Select and Options code, I discarded that option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to detect the dropdown change/select and then fire your div to show. This code assumes that your `.calculator-item-list` div has the CSS `display` property set to `none` e.g. `display:none;`.

**UPDATE:** I suspect OP's html is being created dynamically.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  console.log('fired');
  $(window).on('change', '#nf-field-5', function(){
    console.log('Change hit');
    $('.calculator-item-list').show();
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi! Your answer seems very simple, but I'm having trouble adding the jQuery to my wordpress. Sorry for my lack of knowledge. 
I am using a plugin to add script to header and footer. How should I put this piece of code in that plugin, I have tried by itself and between <script></script> but none works. You can see for yourself at https://comprooroenmalaga.com/vender-oro-online/ .
I effectively have .calculator-item-list as display:none . Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have checked your site. JS will not work without script tags. Please put it back in between the script tags and let me know so I can check again. Also, if you can, make it place the code in the footer rather than the header

Comment: Hi again, I have done as you instructed now, it is in the bottom of the footer inside the script tags. You may check. Thank you!

Comment: See my updated answer and try using that code instead

Comment: Thousand thanks for investing your time is this question. I have tried it but still no luck. Let me know if I can give you any further info in order to get over this problem. Thanks!

Comment: hmmm ok. Check my answer again, use the updated code and let me know when it's done.

Comment: I am able to use this function on the fly in the console, so I suspect it is a scope issue.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you again. So I can see the "fired" on my dev tools, but when changing the option, it doesn't do the "change hit". What do you mean by scope issue? Thank you again.

Comment: Finally I have found the solution, use $(document).on('change' comehow works. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418963/jquery-onchange-function-not-triggering-for-dynamically-created-inputs/13418999
Thousand thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

While you said that you cannot change the Select and Options, I'm going to assume that you mean the values of them.

Change it to this:

```
  <select id="nf-field-5" name="nf-field-5" class="ninja-forms-field nf-
  element" onchange="showDiv(divToShow)">
  <option value="-" selected="selected">Seleccionar kilates</option>
  <option value="14k">14k (joyas)</option>
  <option value="18k">18k (joyas)</option>
  <option value="22k">22k (monedas)</option>
  <option value="24k">24k (lingotes)</option>
  <option value="no-estoy-seguro-a">No estoy seguro/a</option>
  </select>
```

And your div:

```
<span>
 <div class="calculator-item-list" id="divToShow" style="display: none;">
  <div class="item-block calculator-item">
    <p><br>
      <span class="weight">Total de oro:</span>
      <span class="headline2">{calc:Total} €</span> 
      <span class="weight">{calc:Susgramos} gramos</span>
      <span class="large">Le pagamos a {calc:Porgramo} € el gramo</span>    
      <span class="weight">Gastos de valoración: -20€</span>
      <br>
      <span class="weight">Precio final:</span>
      <span class="headline">{calc:Totals} €</span>
    </p>
 </div></div>
</span>
```

Then :

```
 <script>
 function showDiv(id){    

  //For ease
  var x = document.getElementById(id);
  x.style.display = "block";
  }
  <script>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation, I meant I cannot change the actual code, as it is part of the Ninjaform plugin. I can change the values, just I cannot add the "onchange", thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `change` on select or use selected.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dropdown").change(function() {
    $("#show").show();
  })
})
```

```css
#show {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="dropdown">
  <option value="test1">TEST1</option>
  <option value="test2">TEST2</option>
  <option value="test3">TEST3</option>
  <option value="test4">TEST4</option>
  <option value="test5">TEST5</option>
</select>

<div id="show">
  TEST SHOW
</div>
```